# $\langle X\rangle_t = t$

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, brownian-motion

Suppose $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $X_t = |B_t|$. What is the easiest way to see that$$\langle X\rangle_t = t?$$I need this result for a simulation I am running...

Comment: Under the usual definition of "standard Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^d$", this isn't right: the quadratic variation $\langle X \rangle_t$ would be $td$, not $t$.  Is this a typo or something more significant?

Comment: [Hmmm](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1441283).

Comment: Why was this heavily upvoted? Seems to me to be rather offtopic for the site...

Answer (score 4):

This isn't even right in one dimension. In one dimension, $B_t\sim N(0,t)$ and so $\mathbb EX_t=(2\pi t)^{-1/2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|e^{-x^2/(2t)}\,dx=2(2\pi t)^{-1/2}\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2/(2t)}\,dx=2t(2\pi t)^{-1/2}=\sqrt{2t/\pi}$. In general, you would expect square root growth of $X$ and not linear growth as "Brownian motion moves $\approx\sqrt t$ in time $t$".

Maybe you wanted $X_t'=|B_t|^2$. In that case, it's much easier: $|B_t|^2=\sum_{i=1}^d |B^i_t|^2$ where the $B^i_t$ are independent Brownian one-dimensional Brownian motions with volatility $1/d$. In this case $\mathbb E|B^i_t|^2=t/d$ and so $\mathbb EX'_t=t$.

Comment: I think he is asking about the quadratic variation, which is indeed $t$ because $|B_t| = L_t + W_t$ for some other Brownian motion $W$ and a bounded variation process (the local time of $B$ at the origin) $L$.

Comment: I guess it's even easier than that -- we want to find a process $X_t$ such that $|B_t|^2 - X_t$ is a martingale but $|B_t|^2$ can be expressed, as in the answer, via one-dimensional Brownian motions, so this is easy.

Comment: @MateuszWasilewski, you may want to post your comment as an answer---especially considering there is a bounty on this question. (Also, it would be more clear than having the answer in the comment to another answer which says the question is ill-formed.)

Answer (score 2):

Prodded by Jason Rute, I decided to write up a short answer. We want to prove that $X_t^2 - t$ is a martingale. We know that $X_t^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{d} (B_{t}^{i})^2$, where $B_t^{i}$ are independent Brownian motions normalised so that $\mathbb{E} (B_t^{i})^2 = \frac{t}{d}$. Then $$X_t^2 - t = \sum_{i=1}^{d} \left((B_t^i)^2 - \frac{t}{d} \right),$$
is a martingale, being a sum of independent martingales.

Comment: This is an unusual normalization.  The usual definition of "standard Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^d$" is that the components are independent standard Brownian motions.  Under that definition, the quadratic variation of $|B_t|$ would not be $t$ but $td$.

Comment: Yes, that puzzled me a bit also but I guess only OP knows, what he wanted to ask exactly. I should have stated it clearly in my answer that the normalisation I am using is indeed unusual for the standard Brownian motion in $R^{d}$ and I introduce it only to match the exact statement in the question.